# Search results does not match the value entered in search box in SharePoint 2013

Tags: search, search-results

I have created a search results web part. This will return the results of the site pages which are matching the text in the search box.

**Query text used :
{?{SearchBoxQuery} Path:https://xyz/sites/abc/def/mysite123/Pages -Filename:Allitems.aspx -Filename:default.aspx }**

This condition is to fetch the pages matching the text in search box which  are present inside pages folder excluding allitems and default page.

Now say, I am  searching with some key word like : "Apple", Results are coming. In those results, one page is actually having APPLE and that is shown as BOLD in search result. But the other search result is not having APPLE keyword inside the page neither as BOLD in result. But it is coming in search result.

I am not having much experience in troubleshot this kind of search issue.

Can you please help me to sort out this?

Thanks in advance.